# jQuery scroll window off and after back window on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need window off for run a fade out animation from splash page to home.
But in home I need the window on, for make one add class at scroll, then I use  for change the header.
This code not work:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $(this).one('scroll', function() { 
        $(window).off("scroll"); 
        $(".splash").slideUp("800", function() {
            $("html, body").animate({"scrollTop":"0px"},100);
            $(".site").delay(100).animate({"opacity":"1.0"},800);
            $("html, body").on("scroll")
        });
    });
});
```

Can help me to found a solution? thanks!

If need this is the code i use for add class:

```
$(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var sT = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (sT >= 200) {
            $('header').addClass('scroll-header')
        } else {
            $('header').removeClass('scroll-header')
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
 <div class="show_splash">
    <div class="splash fade-in">
        <?php
            $post_id = 93;
            $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
            echo $queried_post->post_content;
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="page" class="site">
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header cf" role="banner">
```

CSS:

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */ }

.cf:after {
  clear: both; }

.cf {
  *zoom: 1; }

.bk_splash{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please include your html and css.

Comment: @Ron.Basco I have add html and css if need more let me know. if can help me I will be very grateful!

Comment: `$("html, body").on("scroll")` is missing a function to handle the scroll event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i have try to not use scroll off, and change with a simple

```
.show_splash{position: fixed;}
```

In this way finely work!!!